# latex organize three images

Tags: image, latex

I am having hard time organizing just three images in latex, I know it souond silly but any help?
this is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,right]{4}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,right]{5}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,left]{6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the desired result it should look like this
[image]

Comment: @whoever voted to migrate this question: please do check the target site for duplicates, the OP x-posted this post. No use to migrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use minipages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-9x16}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-duck}%

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,valign=T]{example-image-duck}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Thank you so much for your answer , but one thing they are not three version of the same image but they are 3 diffrent images , the only problem  with your solution is streching it , I do not need to strech the images . any help ?

Comment: If your images already have the correct aspect ration, just remove all the `height=.2\textheight` and `height=.8\textheight`. Or you can add  the `keepaspectratio` option